# facebook authentication with omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am adding Facebook authentication with omniauth to my application according to Ryan Bates [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

There is a problem with the create function in the authentication controller.
the create function should handle the facebook callback (which seems to be fine).

The error in the log file is:

> NoMethodError (undefined method
> `authentications' for nil:NilClass)

The error refers to this line in the create function in the authentication controller:

> current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])

What do you think is the problem?

Thanks,

Oded

Comment: Post your User and Authentication model please.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked what the error message was saying. See my answer below. If you need help to determine why current_user is nil you'll have to post the code you use to get the current_user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not logged in when you try to authenticate, thus the current_user is nil.  Log in and then authenticate and you will be redirected to the authentications index page.  That is the way that he did it in the railscast.  In the next episode he addresses the user not being logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Your `current_user` is nil, so when you try to access authentications on a nil object you get the error message that you're seeing.

You need to fix your `current_user` method.

Comment: I'm not sure where is the current_user method. I think it's in the "devise" gem. Any way I didn't write this method.

Comment: You're right, it's a helper method provided by devise. Did you run rake db:migrate? Check out the "Getting Started" section for devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Do you know where can I check if the helper is in my application?

Comment: @Oded, Rails helpers are defined in the app/helpers directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too but it's solved.
The reason this error is thrown is that the AuthenticationController’s create action expects there to be a currently logged-in user and tries to find or create a new authentication for that user. As we’re trying to authenticate without having first logged in with a user name and password the current_user variable will be nil.

Follow the link to solve the problem http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast